# how to display a java collections in jquery?

Tags: java, jquery

I have a hash map in java, with key as state code and value as list of county codes.

While displaying in jsp i have to check to see if the county list for each state is greater than zero, If the size is greater than zero then i have to display the state code as hyperlink and when clicked on the hyperlink i should show all the county codes in a small overlay.

Is there a way i can pass java list to a jquery function and display it in a overlay ?

Comment: Send the response to the javascript function as JSON.

Comment: When i click on particular state code, can i grab the list associated with that state code convert to json and send to jquery? or should i make an ajax call to retrieve the list in json format?

Comment: You can do it in both ways, but I think the first option will be easier. Send entire structure in JSON (both state codes and county codes), print only state codes at the main page and then show list of county codes for specific code in an overlay.